# Pass URL string in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On an Apache server if its possible I'd like to pass part of a URL string. For example if a person finds shoes on a search engine and goes to `example.com/shoes` I'd like to redirect them to `m.example.com/shoes` but my .htaccess redirect only passes them to `m.example.com`.

Please help

Comment: TBH I do not understand what you want. Start with showing your current redirect/rewrite rules. Then provide URL example and how it currently redirects. Then show how it SHOULD redirect.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you have asked for:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```